# C# - change behavior of property setter at runtime

Tags: c#

I've run into a slightly contrived coding problem, and I hope someone can tell me if what I want to do is possible in standard C#.

I have a class that originally stored a list of `Foo` objects and made updates to them like so:

```
public class Program
{
    private List<Foo> listOfFoo;

    ...

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var fooObject = (Foo)(listOfFoo[0]);
        fooObject.Name = "name";
        fooObject.Address = "address;"
    }
}
```

I then wanted to replace the `List<Foo>` with a custom class `FooRepository` that uses a backing list of objects of type `FooDto` that are generated from `Foo`, without making any changes to how `listOfFoo` is used in the calling code:

```
public class FooRepository : IEnumerator<Foo>, IEnumerable<Foo>
{
    private List<FooDto> backingList;

    ...

    public void Add(Foo foo)
    {
        backingList.Add(MapToDto(foo));
    }

    public Foo this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            return MapFromDto(backingList[i]);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

But this causes a problem for how updates to objects were originally performed in the calling code, since now accessing the repository doesn't return a reference to the actual object in the backing list, but a newly-generated object instead.  So my question is: keeping this basic design, without modifying anything in the calling code or in `Foo` itself, can I somehow modify `FooRepository` so that the update in `SomeMethod` is still permanently committed to the repository?

I could store two lists in `FooRepository`, one for `FooDto`s and one for `Foo`s, and commit the changes in the `Foo` list to the `FooDto`s each time someone called a method on the repository, but let's assume I don't want to do that.  It seems like my basic strategy is that all accesses to the repository should return an object that can be treated as a `Foo`, but it also has the additional behavior of property assignments being committed to the backing `FooDto`.  If C# supported arbitrary runtime monkey patching, I could do something like:

```
public Foo this[int i]
{
    get
    {
        return MapFromDto(backingList[i]).ForAllProperties(property =>
        {
            property.NewSetter(value => backingList[i].property = value; ...);
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't.  I thought about using System.Reflection.Emit to generate a new child class of `Foo` that overrides the property setters, but none of the properties in `Foo` are marked virtual, so I believe that can't be done.  I could construct a dynamic object that implements everything in `Foo` plus the new setter behavior and use a library like ImpromptuInterface to treat the dynamic object as implementing a certain interface, but `Foo` doesn't implement any interfaces; the properties are simply coded in the class itself.

It seems like the only way to accomplish what I want without either modifying the calling code or `Foo` would be something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463508/NET-CLR-Injection-Modify-IL-Code-during-Run-time) where I modify the IL code of `Foo`'s methods at runtime.  Do I have this right?  Have I overlooked any options?

Thanks.

Comment: Make the new object wrap around the old object so that setting property values on the new object is just tunneled back to the old object.

Comment: Side note: you don't need the cast to `Foo` in `var fooObject = (Foo)(listOfFoo[0]);` since `listOfFoo` is a list of `Foo`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, in my simplification I left out a somewhat important detail.  `Foo` has multiple child classes, objects of which are also stored in the repository.  I could just manually write new wrapper classes that inherit from all of `Foo`'s children and perform the forwarding behavior for all their properties, but then a new wrapper class would have to be manually written each time a new subclass of `Foo` is created.  I was looking into reflection as a way of avoiding that manual work.